# Weird shadow/glow/smear on the right side of all windows

Tags: release-loki, window-manager

Fresh installation of Loki.

Here is a screenshot of the issue. Any way to get rid of it? It only happens on one the two screens (main one).

[image]

Comment: On screenshot it is actually less visible than "live" (might be something with my monitor) but the issue is definitively software related as Ubuntu 16.04 that was on the same machine 15 minutes ago was working fine.

Comment: Personally I don't see anything wrong in these screenshots. I have never done this myself, but maybe you need to adjust the color profiles for your screen in elementary (which could be the reason why it looks different under Ubuntu). Check System Settings → Color. Also are your graphics drivers up-do-date and working correctly?

Comment: Yes, you are right. There is nothing wrong with the screenshot. I just noticed it when I opened it on the second monitor. It still has that weird "smear" on the first one though. So it seems it IS a hardware problem after all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like the issue was hardware after all. After tweaking with the monitor settings and with color presets I managed to mostly resolve the issue.